# Add coupon after order creation in payment pending status in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I am creating order programmatically with order status ***Pending Payment*** in **Woocommerce ver. 3.2.6**.

Can I add **coupon** in existing order (Pending Payment atatus) programmatically?

Comment: Yes this can be done, but is quiet complicated (broad) as you need to check all items in the order and update the data for all of them depending on the coupon type and settings and so also add coupon item to the order and finally update order totals.